# GWT Problem with MySQL Connection

Tags: java, mysql

I am working on a GWT project in which I need to make some MySQL queries. I have handled RPC properly and in the server-side I am trying to make a mysql connection but am running into an exception:

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.newInstance_(Runtime.java:112)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.newInstance(Runtime.java:120)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1013)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:982)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:927)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2412)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2154)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:792)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.newInstance_(Runtime.java:112)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.newInstance(Runtime.java:120)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:381)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:305)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
.
.
.
more
.
.
.

I created a very simple java class to test out my code to confirm that my connection syntax and use is proper, and have confirmed that syntax is not a problem because with the very same code in a simple only main method java app I can create a connection and query the database properly. I have made sure to have mysql-connector-java-5.1.16-bin.jar in the classpath as well as the /lib folder in the WEB-INF folder.

Here is the class that I am using in order to create a connection:

public class DB_Connection {

protected Connection getConnection() {
      Connection conn = null;
      try {
         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
         conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:///",
                                            "", 
                                            "");
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
         ex.printStackTrace();
      }

```
  return conn;
```

}

}

public class Login extends DB_Connection {

public User getUser(String email) {
      User user = new User();
      user.setUserEmail(email);
      String query = "";

```
  try {
     Connection conn = getConnection();
     Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
     ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery(query);
     while(result.next()) {
        user.setUserId(result.getInt("rvuser_id"));
        System.out.println(user.getUserId());
     }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
     ex.printStackTrace();
  }

  return user;
```

}

It seems my problem happens all the way at the beginning in DB_Connection. Does anyone know what is making this happen? It is strange to me, because as a standalone the code works fine.

Another thing I just realized that I am at home now and don't even have access to that database server as it is on a local network and I am not connected through VPN. So it must be failing somehow before it even attempts to make the connection.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with GWT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

com.google.appengine ..
Does it means you are deploying on Google App Engine?
If so, MySQL,JDBC and many other things are restricted.

Comment: No, I have no intent on deploying to App Engine not sure why it's attempting to do something with it. Maybe it is because when I started I generated code from the sample project and then cleaned it up? Where would a setting related to app engine be found?

Comment: Ah wow... I removed app engine from my path and from the run configuration and a connection is being made properly now :) Thank you very much for noticing that this could be the problem! 

I am getting a "Does not contain App Engine SDK in build path now" though the app runs fine. Going to try to remove anything App Engine from it now. I messed myself up with generating test code in the very beginning and just cleaning it up.